# What's the internal difference between a controller and a service?

Tags: angularjs

I just noticed that a friend was using `var vm = this;` in a service. Since this violates the styleguide we're trying to apply I started thinking about how important it is for our code to function properly. Suddenly, I noticed that there might not be many differences between controllers and services/factories (from now on service).

Yes, a controller has access to `$scope` but like services they are simply constructors for objects that are created at some point in the compilation process.

Yes, a controller has a completely different purpose than a service. I know about seperation of concerns and reusability. What I'm wondering as a newbie with half a year of Angular/JavaScript experience is: In what way does Angular treat services and controllers differently? More specifically, what are things that controllers can do that services can't do or vice versa (other than scope access)?

Comment: Probably not a complete answer, so I'll post it as a comment.  A service, factory, controller, etc... are all plain javascript functions, so `var vm = this` will work in all of them, though unless he is going to  `return vm;` at the end of the service, it is not going to work properly.  A service must return the object it is exposing.  Service/factories are also singletons, where controllers are new each time they're loaded.

Comment: If you know they do different things then what do you mean by how are they treated differently? Question is too broad and really doesn't make sense

Comment: @Tom your answer assumes OP is using a `factory`. If it is a `service`,  `this` and thus `vm` as reference are already returned automatically

Comment: @charlietfl I edited my question and tried to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, controllers and services are both JavaScript functions.  The main difference is in how these functions are utilized by the rest of the Angular framework.

[Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#!):

> In Angular, a Controller is defined by a JavaScript **constructor function** that is used to augment the [Angular Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).
>
> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's **constructor function**. A new **child scope** will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope.

[Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services):

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using [dependency injection (DI)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.
>
> Angular services are:
>
> - Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
> - Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.

Based on this, you can see that Controllers *are not* singletons, as services are, and cannot be injected into other Angular components the way that services are.